# Getting IScroll 5 to work with Fancybox 2

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox-2, iscroll

I am working on a project where I am using ISroll 5 to show some html code (that needs to scroll), placed over parts of images.  Another part of the project has a button that when clicked shows a slide show of the images/html described above using Fancybox 2.

The IScroll works fine when just showing the image/html.  However, when I try to show the same image/html in Fancybox -- using a different IScroll instance and code source -- the scrollbar and scrolling are lost.

In searching for solutions, I found a post that suggested IScroll needed to be refreshed after Fancybox dislays.  The reason given is because IScroll needs to get the container size that is initially unavailable with Fancybox starting with a display: none.  So the suggested fix was the following:

```
$("#about-button").fancybox({
    onComplete: function () {
        my_iscroll.refresh();
    }
});
```

The "onComplete" function has been replaced in the newer version of IScroll 5 with "afterLoad".  Given that, I tried the same thing using afterLoad instead with no luck.  Much later, after trying several other ways with no luck, I decided to post.

I created a scaled down version of my project for illustration of the problem.  Starting with the HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow_btn"><button id="gallery_btn">View as Slideshow</button></div>
    <div id="page_contents">    
        <div id="page_image_contents">
            <img class="page_image" src="images/page_items/page4.jpg" width="900" height="620" />
            <div id="page_overlay">
                <div id="page_scroll">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et aliquam lacus, ac venenatis elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed eleifend urna vel purus rhoncus sodales. In faucibus metus non massa viverra vehicula. Ut vel sapien eget nisi dapibus mollis. Aliquam congue felis at justo tristique dictum. Cras eros lectus, euismod eleifend pretium vel, commodo in ipsum. Nam lobortis metus ut placerat fermentum. Nulla non accumsan quam. Pellentesque ligula nibh, convallis et purus vitae, dictum iaculis justo. Sed dolor lacus, interdum vestibulum nisi ut, volutpat iaculis mi. Suspendisse id urna eu quam gravida sagittis. Proin sit amet libero malesuada, sollicitudin tellus eu, aliquam tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed eleifend urna vel purus rhoncus sodales. In faucibus metus non massa viverra vehicula. Ut vel sapien eget nisi dapibus mollis. Aliquam congue felis at justo tristique dictum. Cras eros lectus, euismod eleifend pretium vel, commodo in ipsum.</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var pageScroll = new IScroll('#page_overlay', {
    scrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true,
    shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
    hideScrollbar : false
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

</script>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ============================= Slide Section  =========================== -->
<div id="slide_contents">   
    <div id="slide_image_contents">
        <img class="page_image" src="images/page_items/page4.jpg" width="900" height="620" />
        <div id="slide_overlay">
            <div id="slide_scroll">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et aliquam lacus, ac venenatis elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed eleifend urna vel purus rhoncus sodales. In faucibus metus non massa viverra vehicula. Ut vel sapien eget nisi dapibus mollis. Aliquam congue felis at justo tristique dictum. Cras eros lectus, euismod eleifend pretium vel, commodo in ipsum. Nam lobortis metus ut placerat fermentum. Nulla non accumsan quam. Pellentesque ligula nibh, convallis et purus vitae, dictum iaculis justo. Sed dolor lacus, interdum vestibulum nisi ut, volutpat iaculis mi. Suspendisse id urna eu quam gravida sagittis. Proin sit amet libero malesuada, sollicitudin tellus eu, aliquam tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed eleifend urna vel purus rhoncus sodales. In faucibus metus non massa viverra vehicula. Ut vel sapien eget nisi dapibus mollis. Aliquam congue felis at justo tristique dictum. Cras eros lectus, euismod eleifend pretium vel, commodo in ipsum.</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideScroll = new IScroll('#slide_overlay', {
    scrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true,
    shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
    hideScrollbar : false
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden; /* this is important to prevent the whole page to bounce */
}
#slideshow_btn {
    margin: 10px 10px 6px 0;    
}
#page_contents { 
    width: 900px;   
    height: 620px;
}
#page_image_contents {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 25px;
    border: thin black solid;
}
.page_image {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 900px;
}
#page_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 92px;
    left: 670px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 528px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#page_scroll {
    padding-right: 15px;
}

#slide_contents { 
    width: 900px;   
    height: 620px;
}
#slide_image_contents {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
}
#slide_overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 92px;
    left: 670px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 528px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slide_scroll {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

And jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#gallery_btn").click(function() {

        sGetPage = "#slide_image_contents";
        sGetPageHtml = $(sGetPage).html();

        $.fancybox.open(sGetPageHtml, {
            helpers : {
                overlay : {
                    locked : true 
                }
            },
            autoCenter : false,
            margin : 15,
            padding : 0, 
            fitToView : false,
            autoSize : false,
            scrolling: 'no',
            scrollOutside : true,
            width : 900,
            height : 620,
            afterLoad: function () {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    slideScroll.refresh();
                }, 0);
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

Thanks to anyone willing to look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`afterLoad:` and `.refresh()` are both working fine in your example. The problem is that the fancy box script makes duplicate IDs and then iScroll does not know which element to target. IDs must always be unique to the page.

The solution is to use classes instead, and to move the entire iscroll code into the fancybox callback since the element we want to target will not exist until fancybox is called. So for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var pageScroll = new IScroll('#page_overlay', {
    scrollbars: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    interactiveScrollbars: true,
    shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
    hideScrollbar : false
});

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

    $("#gallery_btn").click(function() {

        sGetPage = "#slide_image_contents";
        sGetPageHtml = $(sGetPage).html();

        $.fancybox.open(sGetPageHtml, {
            helpers : {
                overlay : {
                    locked : true 
                }
            },
            autoCenter : false,
            margin : 15,
            padding : 0, 
            fitToView : false,
            autoSize : false,
            scrolling: 'no',
            scrollOutside : true,
            width : 900,
            height : 620,
            afterShow : function () {
                var slideScroll = new IScroll('.fancybox-wrap .slide_overlay', {
                    scrollbars: true,
                    mouseWheel: true,
                    interactiveScrollbars: true,
                    shrinkScrollbars: 'scale',
                    hideScrollbar : false
                });
            }
        }); 
    });

});
```

Note that I am specifically targetting the element with the proper class that is *inside* the fancybox container ('.fancybox-wrap .slide_overlay').

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GM4Yb/)** a working jsfiddle.

Comment: You are exactly right on the mark!  I made the changes you suggested to my much larger project and it worked perfectly.  By the way, to anyone looking at his jsfiddle example, it is working despite how it looks: it is just missing the image that would otherwise be being overlayed by the scrolling text.  Nice work pschueller!